# CSS options to deal with static width but variable height images

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

I am dealing with some external images that have a static width, but the product height is variable.

So when displayed in a list, the rows are very uneven in height and looks a mess when viewed on a mobile. The platform I am using outputs thumbnail images with 80px x 80px, but of course, some images look a mess due to the differing aspect ratios.

What is the best solution to deal with images that have a fixed width, but a variable height to get consistent thumbnails that are not too distorted?

```
[![52px height][1]][1]
[![135px height][2]][2]
[![135px height][3]][3]
[![135px height][4]][4]
[![114px height][5]][5]

https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4137QNeZPuL._SL500_SL135_.jpg
https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41XYDSg9cgL._SL500_SL135_.jpg
https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uKMqjNcYL._SL500_SL135_.jpg
https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51aDh6YhzxL._SL500_SL135_.jpg
https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qdmedWltL._SL500_SL135_.jpg
```

Comment: What you mean by the best solution ? are you asking for design suggests ? which is the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes best to avoid js for this.

But if you want to avoid background images and use img elements, [try the object-fit property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit).  Browser support is good except for IE/Edge, so that would be a case of progressive enhancement, ie/edge would not look the same, but it would be functional, and presentable - just not as streamlined as other browsers.

There are a bunch of other clipping methods available, but really, this is the kind of thing object-fit was made for.

Comment: object-fit: contain did the job perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this, I'd recommend looking into doing it all in css.

```
background-image: url("https://www.example.com/image.jpg");
background-size: cover; // use different options for different effects
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center; 
height: 80px; 
width: 80px;
```